# How to find local server via android emulator?

Tags: android, tomcat, servlets, android-emulator

I have tried to load page with address `http://127.0.0.1:8080/1` on my android emulator at that time my app and emulator browser can't find this page. Browser on PC can load page and all work perfect. Servlet(which lies in Tomcat in this PC in ubuntu 13.04) create this page. Apache server for php also can't work on emulator. How can i find this page and connect to my local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` on the emulator is the emulator itself.

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) points out that your development machine that runs your emulator is reachable via `10.0.2.2`.

Comment: Sounds like the host (laptop) may be reachable at 10.0.2.1, from the emulator. Just an educated guess.

Comment: @matthudson: No, `10.0.2.2` should work, if `127.0.0.1` works on the development machine itself.

Comment: I would think that any local ip should also be reachable, e.g. 192.168.0.17, but i can't seem to get that to work.